# Single selection of cards in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props

I'm a beginner at React and I'm trying to implement single selection on my cards where in only one card can be selected at a time and the selected card is highlighted.
This is my borderCard component

```
export const BorderCard = styled.div`
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: ${(props) =>
    props.selected ? "#E8F1FF" : "#FFFFFF"};
  border: ${(props) =>
      props.selected ? "1.5px solid #2375A4" : "1px solid #d5dde3"}
`;
```

This BorderCard is then used in my PaymentCard component

```
const PaymentCard = ({ option }) => {
  
  return (
    <BorderCard style={{ marginTop: "10px"}} selected  >
      
      <Row>
        <StatusHead style={{ fontWeight: 500 }}>{option.optionText}</StatusHead>
        <StatusHead>₹ {formatAmount(option.totalPayable)}</StatusHead>
      </Row>
   </BorderCard>
  );
};
```

And finally all these payment cards are displayed one after the other using maps.

```
return ( 
    <ScrollableBox>
           {paymentOptions.map((option, index) => (
                <PaymentCard key={index} option ={option} onChange = {() => setisSelected(index)}
                />
              ))}
     </ScrollableBox>
           <Row style={{ marginTop: "15px", alignItems: "flex-start" }}>
                <BsExclamationCircle
                  style={{
                    fontSize: "20px",
                    paddingTop: "2px",
                    margin: "0 8px",
                  }}
                />
                <SubText>
                  {paymentOptions.length > 0
                    ? paymentOptions[0].lateChargeText
                    : ""}
                </SubText>
              </Row>
};
```

I have prop called selected in the BorderCard component and on passing it in the PaymentCard component all the cards are selected instead of one. Secondly in the final return statement I have paymentOptions[0] hard coded where it should be based on the on the array element (i.e card) currently selected. For that I understand I can use the findIndex() method to get the index of the card currently selected but I'm not able to write a function to handleSelection and to appropriately use the selected prop in my BorderCard component. Should I use a state to store the selected card instead? Please help me understand this.

```
const handleSelection = ;
const selectedIndex = paymentOptions.findIndex(handleSelection);
```

[image]

Comment: I would lift up curent selected borad up to common component. On mounted BorderCard i would assing some uuid to it. When it will be selected it sends up current selected card id (eg. onSelect). After current selected card will change all child BorderCard will check that curent selected id is its own id.

Comment: What does lifting selected board upto common component mean?

Comment: [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

Comment: I'm using functional components so I am a bit confused as to how to lift state up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass `selected` and `onChange` as properties in `PaymentCard`:

```
const PaymentCard = ({ option, selected, onChange }) => {
  
  return (
    <BorderCard style={{ marginTop: "10px"}} selected={selected}  >
      
      <Row onClick={onChange}>
        <StatusHead style={{ fontWeight: 500 }}>{option.optionText}</StatusHead>
        <StatusHead>₹ {formatAmount(option.totalPayable)}</StatusHead>
      </Row>
   </BorderCard>
  );
};
```

Then mark as selected according to `isSelected` value:

```
const [isSelected, setisSelected] = useState(null);

//...
{paymentOptions.map((option, index) => (
     <PaymentCard key={index} option ={option} selected={isSelected === index} onChange = {() => setisSelected(index)}/>
))}
```

You can get the selected option using the isSelected value:

```
<SubText>
   {paymentOptions.length > 0 && isSelected
       ? paymentOptions[isSelected].lateChargeText
       : ""}
</SubText>
```

[Working Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vm7ett?file=src%2FApp.js)

Comment: the selected prop is already passed in the BorderCard and as a result I get all the cards selected, BorderCard and PaymentCard are two separate components. How can I pass the selected prop again in the PaymentCard component

Comment: They are two separated components, but PaymentCard renders BorderCard and it needs the selected property too.

Comment: Also you need to pass the onChange callback, that way when card is clicked, the onChange function is dispatched

Comment: Yes, I updated my answer, you need to pass the onChange too

Comment: Yes, that is correct! the onClick event could be in BorderCard

Comment: I am still getting both the cards as selected and the `<Subtext>` is hidden by default now but reappears on clicking the second card. How do I set the first card selected as default

Comment: Here you can set the default value const [isSelected, setisSelected] = useState(0); the first card will selected by default

Comment: Hey please check the image I've added in the original post, both of my cards are selected and it is because I've passed the selected prop in the BorderCard and hence all the cards have it. Where should I keep the selected prop so as to only highlight the selected card

Comment: try this <BorderCard style={{ marginTop: '10px' }} selected={selected} onClick={onChange}>

Comment: See this working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-vm7ett?file=src%2FApp.js